# type initializer for 'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer' threw an exception in c# for cash drawer

Tags: c#, point-of-sale

I am new in POS system, so if I miss out any info let me know will edit with it.
I have installed a WINFORM on other PC through setup, and I want top open a cash drawer attached to it on form load. I have used Microsoft.PointOfService dll. And heres my code :

```
  public partial class CashRegister : Form
{


    CashDrawer myCashDrawer;
    PosExplorer explorer;

    public CashRegister()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        explorer = new Microsoft.PointOfService.PosExplorer();
        DeviceInfo ObjDevicesInfo = explorer.GetDevice("CashDrawer", "EP-125k");
        //myCashDrawer = (CashDrawer) explorer.CreateInstance(ObjDevicesInfo);
       // myCashDrawer.OpenDrawer();
    }
    public void OpenCashDrawer()
    {
        myCashDrawer.Open();
        myCashDrawer.Claim(1000);
        myCashDrawer.DeviceEnabled = true;
        myCashDrawer.OpenDrawer();
        myCashDrawer.DeviceEnabled = false;
        myCashDrawer.Release();
        myCashDrawer.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void CashRegister_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //  myCashDrawer.OpenDrawer();
    }
}
```

But when it executes it gives following error:

> type initializer for 'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer' threw an exception

Can any one help.

Thanks

EDIT : this is the TypeInitializationException error's details

```
`See the end of this message for details on invoking 
 just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for          'Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer' threw an exception. ---> Microsoft.PointOfService.PosLibraryException: Failed to open registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\POSfor.NET\ControlAssemblies.
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.AssemblyLoader.Scan()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.AssemblyLoader.Scan()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer.ScanForSOAssemblies()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer.Refresh()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer..ctor()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.Management.Explorer..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: What is your inner exception?

Comment: I am sorry but whats an inner exception.

Comment: @user2454135: Post the *full* stack trace - as much information as you have. That's likely to include at least two "levels" of exception: the TypeInitializationException and the "inner" exception that caused it.

Comment: I have coded above codes on another PC which doesnt have drawer attached and downloaded microsoft.pointofservice dll on it and it doesnt shows any error, but on another it gives TypeInitializationException error, do I need to install dll on other PC too ??

Comment: It likely means you're missing an referenced assembly.  Check to make sure you've deployed all the right DLLs.

Comment: @PeterRitchie It works fine on other PC where I have attached the dll, but I dont have drawer attached to it. So do I need to install dll file on other PC where setup is installed?

Comment: `ScanForSOAssemblies` is a dead giveaway what it is doing.  The inner exception likely has some important details.  If it works on another PC, that PC likely has the needed DLL.  Without more detail, I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed thanks to all of you, it was just a silly misout.nstalled POS for .Net v1.12.exe and it does not gives any error.